Okta-Vue AuthSdkError: “Could not load PKCE codeVerifier from storage.”
After registration, the user is to be redirected to the /welcome route on my vue app. Occasionally, instead of displaying the component at that route, the following error text is displayed where router-view component would appear on App.vue:

AuthSdkError: Could not load PKCE codeVerifier from storage. This may
indicate the auth flow has already completed or multiple auth flows
are executing concurrently.

This seems to happen consistently if you wait at the Okta registration screen for 15 minutes before returning. For some users, it happens every time without waiting.
Reproduction Steps?

Deploy vue app with okta-vue per sdk versions provided here
Configure OIDC single page app with initiate login at desired route (/welcome)
Set brand settings for login page to default to application
Ensure self service registration is enabled in vue apps profile enrollment policy
Go to custom URL for Okta org
Click on “sign up” or other text for creating an account
Wait for 15+ minutes before submitting account creation form
Click button in email to verify account
Observe AuthSdkError error text between App.vue header and footer

SDK Versions
System:

OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
CPU: (16) x64 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz
Memory: 1.91 GB / 15.67 GB

Binaries:

Node: 18.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 8.19.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD

Browsers:

Edge: Chromium (127.0.2651.74)
Internet Explorer: 11.0.19041.4355

npmPackages:

@okta/okta-vue: ^5.0.0 => 5.7.0
@vue/cli-plugin-babel: ^5.0.8 => 5.0.8
@vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ^5.0.8 => 5.0.8
@vue/cli-service: ^5.0.8 => 5.0.8
@vue/compat: ^3.1.0-0 => 3.4.27
@vue/compiler-sfc: ^3.1.0-0 => 3.4.27
vue: ^3.1.0-0 => 3.4.27
vue-fuse: ^4.1.1 => 4.1.1
vue-router: ^4.0.0 => 4.3.2

Additional Information:
This is vue 3 but I think I am not taking full advantage of vue 3 features. I am not using composition API. I export default to initiate app.vue and not “new Vue”. I don’t use “new Vue” syntax anywhere.
